# Auto expiration of messages in Camel

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have a system implementing Camel and ActiveMQ for communication between some servers. I would like to know if there is a way to automatically expire and clear-out messages sent to a queue after X period of time. Since the originating server (filling the queue) wont know if anyone is picking up the messages, I don't want my queue to grow until its so large that something crashes. Bonus karma points to someone who can help and provide the java dsl way to implement this feature.

**Solution**

```
// expire message after 2 minutes
long ttl = System.currentTimeMillis() + 120000;
// send our info one-way to the group topic
camelTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader("jms:queue:stats", ExchangePattern.InOnly, stats, "JMSExpiration", ttl);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JMS provides a mechanism for you to set expiry on messages. Look at the below two references

1. [setJMSExpiration(long expiration)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSExpiration%28long%29): per message
2. [ActiveMQ: How do I set the message expiration](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-set-the-message-expiration.html): per destionation/per message

Comment: Looks promising, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 3):

Also mind that clocks between client - broker need to be in sync, for the expiry to work properly. If the clocks is not in sync, then the expiry set from the client, may already be expired when the message is received on the broker. Or the client time is ahead of the broker, so the expiry is longer than the 10 secs.

It kinda beats me why the expiry is client time based. So AMQ offers a plugin, to fix this by realigning the time, to be broker based only. See https://activemq.apache.org/timestampplugin.html

Answer (score 2):

Well the 
    setJMSExpiration(long expiration):

is something you MUST not call when you are the client. See my talk on this a bit on the ActiveMQ forum.

https://apache-qpid-developers.2158895.n2.nabble.com/MRG-Java-JMS-Expiration-td7171854.html

Comment: In your message on the forum it looked as if you wanted 10 minute expiration but had instead set 10 seconds. ex. (10 * (60 * 1000)) vs (10 * 1000)

Comment: @Mondain nope, I wanted 10 seconds. 10 minutes is an Qpid default setting of when the expired messages are cleared from the queues. For example: you sent a message to the queue having expiration set to 10 seconds, so after 10 seconds the messages is expired by QPid and no consumer can consume it, but de-facto the message is delete bu QPid when the Removal Policy Thread(s) kick in, and the default setting is that they kick in after 10 minutes

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood what you had posted there.

Answer (score 2):

On our side we choose to add expiration time to specific destinations by using a camel route deployed in the ActiveMQ service itself.

The only thing to do is creating a XML file like the following with name e.g. `setJMSExpiration.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <camelContext id="camel-set-expiration" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <!-- Copy route for each destination to expire -->
    <route id="setJMSExpiration.my.queue.dlq">
      <from uri="broker:queue:MY.QUEUE.DLQ"/>
        <setHeader headerName="JMSExpiration">
          <!-- Message will expire after 1 day -->
          <spel>#{T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis() + 86400000}</spel>
        </setHeader>
      <to uri="broker:queue:MY.QUEUE.DLQ"/>
    </route>
    <route id="setJMSExpiration.another.queue">
      <from uri="broker:queue:ANOTHER.QUEUE"/>
        <setHeader headerName="JMSExpiration">
          <!-- Message will expire after 5 days -->
          <spel>#{T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis() + 432000000}</spel>
        </setHeader>
      <to uri="broker:queue:ANOTHER.QUEUE"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>
</beans>
```

and import it in your `activemq.xml` config with:

```
<!-- Add default Expiration (file in the same directory) -->
<import resource="setJMSExpiration.xml"/>
```

Alternatively you can also provide specific [per destination policies](https://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html) if you don't want the expired messages to reach the ActiveMQ.DLQ queue.

```
<policyEntry queue="MY.QUEUE.DLQ">
    <deadLetterStrategy>
        <sharedDeadLetterStrategy processExpired="false" />
    </deadLetterStrategy>
</policyEntry>
<policyEntry queue="ANOTHER.QUEUE">
    <deadLetterStrategy>
        <sharedDeadLetterStrategy processExpired="false" />
    </deadLetterStrategy>
</policyEntry>
```

The only limitation of this way is that you cannot easily use wildcards as it is coded here (you can, but it'll need some adaptations by using JMS destination header in the camel route).

We try to let the producers to define the timeToLive (and force them as much as possible) but it is not always possible to force them to change their code, this to minimize the number of such routes.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint option **timeToLive** (http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) worked for me as a solution for the described problem, messages are removed from a queue after 300000 miliseconds.
e.g. "activemq:Q.QUEUE?disableReplyTo=true&**timeToLive**=300000"

Setting header JMSExpiration, didn't cause removing message from a queue automatically in my case. 
But this doc https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwsf_prjms_timetolive.html gave me a hint.